# Why does a variable's equal 0 despite its real value is 1?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Press "YES" button and try to change the number by pressing "-" and "+" buttons.

I'm getting an amount variable from html using next() method.

In both decrease and increase functions I console.log() the amount variable and for some reason it is equal 0 though its real value is 1. And also in the line 20 of js file I console.log() the number and its value is 1.

**How to get the number correctly?**

```js
$(function() {
  function decrease() {
    let amount = Number($(this).next().next().children("div").eq(1).text());
    console.log(amount);
    if (amount - 1 >= 1) {
      Number($(this).next().next().children("div").eq(1).text(amount - 1));
    }
  }

  function increase() {
    let amount = Number($(this).next().next().children("div").eq(1).text());
    console.log(amount);
    $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(1).text(amount + 1);
  }

  let flag = false
  
  $(".yes").click(function() {
    if (flag === false) {
      $(this).css("background", "rgb(255, 74, 74)");
      $(this).next().next().css("opacity", 1);
      console.log(Number($(this).next().next().children("div").eq(1).text()));
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(0).bind("click", decrease);
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(2).bind("click", increase);
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(0).css("cursor", "pointer");
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(2).css("cursor", "pointer");
      flag = true;
    } else {
      $(this).css("background", "transparent");
      $(this).next().next().css("opacity", 0.5);
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(0).unbind("click", decrease);
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(2).unbind("click", increase);
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(0).css("cursor", "default");
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(2).css("cursor", "default");
      flag = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.product-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 97px 97px 97px;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr auto 1fr auto;
  /* max-width: 1200px; */
  /* row-gap: 25px; */
}

.product-list .name,
.product-list .indent1,
.product-list .yes,
.product-list .indent2,
.product-list .selector {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.name {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.yes {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selector {
  /* grid-area: selector; */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.selector div:nth-child(1) {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.selector div:nth-child(3) {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form class="product-list">
  <div class="name">
    <div>Product 1</div>
    <div>2 units</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent1"></div>
  <div class="yes">
    <div>YES</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent2"></div>
  <div class="selector">
    <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">-</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; border: none; background: transparent; cursor: default;">1</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <div>Product 2</div>
    <div>2 units</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent1"></div>
  <div class="yes">
    <div>YES</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent2"></div>
  <div class="selector">
    <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">-</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; border: none; background: transparent; cursor: default;">1</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <div>Product 3</div>
    <div>2 units</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent1"></div>
  <div class="yes">
    <div>YES</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent2"></div>
  <div class="selector">
    <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">-</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; border: none; background: transparent; cursor: default;">1</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">+</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://codepen.io/CodingNinja619/pen/LYeVRXL

Comment: Your selector is totally wrong.  Take a close look at `$(this).next().next().children("div").eq(1)` in *both functions* and see if you can work out what it should be. Is this a homework project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selectors` for the result text (amount) are wrong and they are not pulling the right text. This is why it fails to do manipulation or set the text

You need to change the selectors in both `increase()` and `decrease()` functions

***FROM***

```
$(this).next().next().children("div").eq(1).text()
```

***To***

```
$(this).next().text() //for decrease as element is next to it
$(this).prev().text() //for increase as element is before
```

---

<kbd>**Working Code below**</kbd>

```js
$(function() {
  function decrease() {
    let amount = Number($(this).next().text());
    console.log(amount);
    if (amount - 1 >= 1) {
      Number($(this).next().text(amount - 1));
    }
  }

  function increase() {
    let amount = Number($(this).prev().text());
    console.log("y" + amount);
    $(this).prev().text(amount + 1);
  }

  let flag = false
  $(".yes").click(function() {
    if (flag === false) {
      $(this).css("background", "rgb(255, 74, 74)");
      $(this).next().next().css("opacity", 1);
      console.log(Number($(this).next().next().children("div").eq(1).text()));
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(0).bind("click", decrease);
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(2).bind("click", increase);

      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(0).css("cursor", "pointer");
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(2).css("cursor", "pointer");

      flag = true;
    } else {
      $(this).css("background", "transparent");
      $(this).next().next().css("opacity", 0.5);
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(0).unbind("click", decrease);
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(2).unbind("click", increase);

      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(0).css("cursor", "default");
      $(this).next().next().children("div").eq(2).css("cursor", "default");

      flag = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.product-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 97px 97px 97px;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr auto 1fr auto;
  /* max-width: 1200px; */
  /* row-gap: 25px; */
}

.product-list .name,
.product-list .indent1,
.product-list .yes,
.product-list .indent2,
.product-list .selector {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.name {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.yes {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selector {
  /* grid-area: selector; */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.selector div:nth-child(1) {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.selector div:nth-child(3) {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form class="product-list">
  <div class="name">
    <div>Product 1</div>
    <div>2 units</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent1"></div>
  <div class="yes">
    <div>YES</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent2"></div>
  <div class="selector">
    <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">-</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; border: none; background: transparent; cursor: default;">1</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">+</div>
  </div>

  <div class="name">
    <div>Product 2</div>
    <div>2 units</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent1"></div>
  <div class="yes">
    <div>YES</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent2"></div>
  <div class="selector">
    <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">-</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; border: none; background: transparent; cursor: default;">1</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">+</div>
  </div>

  <div class="name">
    <div>Product 3</div>
    <div>2 units</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent1"></div>
  <div class="yes">
    <div>YES</div>
  </div>
  <div class="indent2"></div>
  <div class="selector">
    <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">-</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; border: none; background: transparent; cursor: default;">1</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 15px; background: transparent; width: 35px;">+</div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Easy, that's fine, I thought I missed smthng and that's why there was a downvote. In every other case, it happens (outside our circle of control), lets spend our energy in answering more questions :)

Comment: @Dorvalla and by the way what rules I didn't follow?

Comment: @Tushar yes it did, thank you! But I don't understand why I should change the selectors this way. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Sure, `.next ()` finds the next element based on the current content, with decrease, the text element is after the decrease button so we used `next(),` for increase the text element is before the increase button, so we have used `prev()`. For your case (original code) the selectors you wrote were not targeting the text element. Hope this helps

Comment: So in both `decrease()` and `increase()` functions `$(this)` element is the button, either left or right, yes?

Comment: yes $(this) refers to current context - which means for decrease() its the decrease button and for increase() its the increase button, and then you find the selector based on $(this)